# Probability of reaching goal in n steps?

Tags: binomial-distribution, monte-carlo, markov-process

Consider a simple grid-like setup where an agent starts at the first state (s0) and has to reach the absorbing state (G):

```
| s0 | s1 | G |
```

Also, when it tries to get from s0 to s1 or from s1 to G, there's a 50% chance that it succeeds (it can only go rightwards). The transition function would be:

$P(s_0 | s_0) = 0.5$, $P(s_1 | s_0) = 0.5$

$P(G | s_1) = 0.5$, $P(s_1 | s_1) = 0.5$

$P(G | G) = 1$

(The probabilities that aren't shown are equal to $0$).

I needed to know the probabilities that the agent reaches the goal in $n$ steps (let's call it $P(X = n)$), so I wrote a little program to run a Monte Carlo simulation and return estimates of the probabilities. I got something like this:

```
(2, 0.25002725)
(3, 0.250135)
(4, 0.187178)
(5, 0.12498175)
(6, 0.0783475)
(7, 0.0469035)
(8, 0.02724025)
(9, 0.015646)
(10, 0.00877575)
...
```

Where `(n, p)` means that $P(X = n) = p$.

The results look nice, but I'd like to know how to calculate these probabilities analytically. I tried thinking about $P(X = n)$ as the probability of getting 2 successes (getting two successful moves from one state to the other) with 50% probability in $n$ trials in a binomial distribution setting, but the values did not match.

For example, for 3 steps:
$$P(x = 3) = \binom{3}{2} * 0.5^2 * 0.5 = 0.375$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the other transition probabilities? You write that $P(s_0\to s_1)=0.5$, but what are $P(s_0\to s_0)$ and $P(s_0\to G)$? Similarly, you write that $P(s_1\to G)=0.5$, but what are $P(s_1\to s_0)$ and $P(s_1\to s_1)$?

Comment: Your use of "tries" suggests that somehow this agent is making decisions and has some kind of control over the evolution of the state--it isn't entirely probabilistic.  What is the decision mechanism?

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks for the feedback, I added them now

Comment: @whuber, I forgot to mention that it can only go rightwards. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes.  You will want to investigate the Negative Binomial distribution or the (most basic part of) the theory of Markov chains.

Comment: @whuber Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will take $n$ steps to reach $G$ if and only if, in a sequence of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials with parameter $p=0.5$, you had $n-2$ failures before seeing the first $2$ successes.

(Read this a couple of times and ponder. Convince yourself that this is indeed an equivalence.)

Why cast your problem in these less intuitive terms? Because the number $n$ of failures before seeing the first $r$ successes in a sequence of iid Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$ is precisely (one of several equivalent definitions of) the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

So you are looking for the negbin mass with parameters $(n-2,2,p)$. (Be careful, there are different parameterizations of the negbin in common use.) Let's test your simulation using R:

```
> nn <- 2:10
> cbind(nn,dnbinom(nn-2,size=2,prob=0.5))
      nn            
 [1,]  2 0.250000000
 [2,]  3 0.250000000
 [3,]  4 0.187500000
 [4,]  5 0.125000000
 [5,]  6 0.078125000
 [6,]  7 0.046875000
 [7,]  8 0.027343750
 [8,]  9 0.015625000
 [9,] 10 0.008789062
```

Note that this only works because both transition probabilities are equal. (It would also work for other *identical* probabilities.) In the general case, you can write down recursive expressions for your probabilities.

---

So, why does an approach using the binomial distribution *not* work, where we calculate $P(n)$ as the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes in $n$ iid Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$?

The key problem is that the binomial approach considers possible sequences of trials that it *shouldn't* consider, because we have already arrived at the absorbing state $G$. And vice versa. (And the negbin approach does *not* commit this error.)

For instance, suppose we want to find $P(3)$. The binomial approach considers the eight possible sequences of successes (S, where we move to the next state) and failures (F, where we do not move to the next state):

- FFF
- SFF
- FSF
- FFS
- SSF
- SFS
- FSS
- SSS

It then counts how many of these sequences contain exactly two S, which are 3/8 (SSF, SFS, FSS), or 37.5%.

However, this is not the correct way of counting the steps to reach $G$. One the one hand, the trajectory SSF should *not* be counted for $P(3)$, but for $P(2)$, since we have already arrived at $G$ after the second step. And on the other hand, the binomial approach does not consider trajectories of the form SF...FS, where an S is followed by *multiple* Fs and then an S.

This is precisely why the probabilities for *observing $n-2$ failures before observing $2$ successes* and for *observing precisely $2$ successes in a sequence of $n$ trials* are not equal, and why we need the negative binomial distribution (which models the first probability) in addition to the binomial one (which models the second one).

Comment: Thank you very much! But if I may ask, what is wrong about the binomial distribution setting I first thought of? I can understand why negbin works but can't really understand why binomial won't work.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your approach. Does this help?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you very much!!